# What should we use as resolution while creating PSD to HTML for ionic app?

Tags: ionic-framework

I am making an IOS app using ionic framework, I have the PSD ready with me, now its time to make HTML for iPhone resolutions. I found there are two resolutions.

Logical Resolution [ Device height Width for eg iPhone 6 -> 667*375 ]
Pixel Resolution [ Pixel Resolution for eg iPhone 6 -> 1134 * 750 ]

My question is which resolution I should choose ?

In my first app I used default Ionic css, so not aware of it. Can anybody help ?

Answer (score 0):

I often advise the designers I work with to use the iPhone 6/7 @1x resolution: 375*667px.

Thus, they can use the heights & widths recommended by the iOS guidelines. For example: a status bar should have a 20pts height so 20px at @1x resolution.

In general, regardless of the resolution chosen, the most important is to have a properly scaled design, that is, each component has the right size.

About Ionic, it already respects the iOS & Google guidelines (for most components), so you don't have to worry about it.